# replace the element instead of append

Tags: jquery

I have the following code where i need to replace the newly created TD column with the new option from the dropdown select. Here is my code

```
$("#myselction").change(function(e) {
    var neData = $("#myselction").val();
    $("table.data thead tr").append("<th>Idea</th>");
    $("table.data tr:gt(0)").append("<td>" + neData + "</td>");
});
```

It is appending the data correctly at the end of the table, but everytime i select new option from dropdown, it adds another td column, instead i want to replace it with the one already created and if its new one create it first time.

Alo i am using the following function to add/remove class for odd and even

```
    zebRaRows('.data tbody tr:odd td', 'odd');
function zebRaRows(selector, className){
  $(selector).removeClass(className).addClass(className);
}
```

How do i add the above to the dynamically created column

Comment: can you show your html table code ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired behavior is different depending on whether it is the first time the action is occurring or not. In this case, have a boolean flag which records the first time the event occurs. The first time, append the new `<td>`; subsequent times, overwrite it.

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Qgj52/)

```
var firstTime = true;

$("#myselction").change(function(e) {
    var neData = $("#myselction").val();

    if (firstTime) {
        $("table.data thead tr").append("<th>Idea</th>");
        $("table.data tr:gt(0)").append("<td>" + neData + "</td>");
        firstTime = false;
    }
    else {
        $("table.data tr:gt(0) td:last-child").html(neData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Anyway your answer is better way. up

Comment: Thanks Pal, But how do i enable the functionality of ZebRaClass in in my original code to this, my half problem yougave a good solution for this, appreciate it +2

Comment: Here is the Updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qgj52/2/, here the drop is selected, but when the default is selected, it still shows, how can i hide that like the default is chosen, show nothing and after navigating, i again choose default, it should hide column, i tried remove, detach, but none of them work properly

Comment: @user2851355 I would handle the case of the 'default' selection with its own conditional, as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qgj52/5/). The 'Zebra Row' effect just sounds like you want alternating colors for odd/even rows. In that case, The css [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

you need to replace append() which append with [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which replace.

try:

```
$("selector of element to replace").html("<td>" + neData + "</td>");
```

[Here is fiddler for html demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/w5vTu/)

Answer (score 0):

use .html() to create a new .

```
$("table.data tr:gt(0)").html("<td>" + neData + "</td>");
```

Comment: it is not adding at the end, it is adding to the start, vanishing the whole table